# Unknown column but the column exists using two inner joins

Tags: mysql, join

I have this SQL:

```
select * 
from products_to_mz
join mz_categories on products_to_mz.product_type = mz_categories.id
join products_to_mz as ptm on products.products_id = ptm.product_id
order by products_to_mz.product_type
```

I'm trying to get from the database something like this:

```
product_id, product_type_id, product_type_name
```

(the columns have different names, but I want you to know what's the point of this).

The problem is that I get this SQL error when the products.products_id it actually exists.

> SQL ERROR: `#1054 - Unknown column 'products.products_id' in 'on clause'`

Here are the structures from the second join tables:

products_to_mz structure:

[image]

products structure:

[image]

Comment: It looks like you're trying to do a self join, but it is not clear why.  Please include some sample data and the expected output.

Comment: probably a typo. "join products_to_mz as ptm" should be "join products as ptm"

Comment: You should use **mz_categories.products_id**  instead of **products.products_id**

Comment: Hi. Please read & act on [mcve]. Hi. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & 

ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image 

only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what can't be given in 

text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key. Always google an error message & number with & without your particular names & code. Read *all* answers to learn of many ways it can arise.

Answer (score 1):

in your query **products** alias is not defined anywhere, suppose it is for products_to_mz then query should be

```
SELECT *
FROM   products_to_mz products
       JOIN mz_categories ON  products_to_mz.product_type = mz_categories.id
       JOIN products_to_mz AS ptm ON  products.products_id = ptm.product_id
ORDER BY
       products.product_type
```

**OR**

```
 SELECT *
    FROM   products_to_mz 
           JOIN mz_categories ON  products_to_mz.product_type = mz_categories.id
           JOIN products ON  products.products_id = ptm.product_id
    ORDER BY
           products_to_mz .product_type
```